# How to programatically start and stop lottie animations in .NET Maui

Tags: c#, .net, maui, lottie

I would like to be able to play an animation in my .NET task project whenever I add a task.

Right now I'm able to use SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui to load and animate a lottie file. I can also trigger an animation with a tapgesture. It plays the animation but when I press again it does not play the animation again or it keeps repeating the animation without stopping.

I tried using the property repeatcount. I tried setting it to -1(keep repeating), 0, 1

I have also tried using the duration, isvisible, and isenabled along with a timer. An event gets fired when the duration of the animation has passed and I hide the animation again. That works however only once. I can't get it to run again after that.

Xaml

```
                <skia:SKLottieView
                        x:Name="animatedPlusIcon"
                        Source="WhiteCheck.json"
                        HeightRequest="150"
                        WidthRequest="150"
                        RepeatCount="0"
                        IsAnimationEnabled="True">
                <skia:SKLottieView.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </skia:SKLottieView.GestureRecognizers>
            </skia:SKLottieView>
```

Code behind

```
    void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    animatedPlusIcon.IsAnimationEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround i found is: Each time you create a new task, you could remove Lottie first and then add it again with custom settings.  Such like the following:

In xaml, add it in a mystack

```
<StackLayout x:Name="mystack">
    <skl:SKLottieView
    .... 
    </skl:SKLottieView>
</StackLayout>
```

Each time you create a task， first remove it and then add it：

```
(mystack as StackLayout).Clear();
SKLottieView myanimatedview = new SKLottieView();
var a = new SKFileLottieImageSource();
a.File = "dotnetbot.json";
myanimatedview.Source = a;
myanimatedview.RepeatCount = 3;
(mystack as StackLayout).Add(myanimatedview);
```

For more info, you could refer to [SKLottieView](https://mono.github.io/SkiaSharp.Extended/api/ui-maui/sklottieview.html). As we can see there is not many APIs for us as it is still a perview. You could also report an issue on Github: [SKLottie Issues on Github](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended/issues)

Hope it works for you.