# Lottie animation (using SkiaSharp) does not display inside collectionview.empyview content view

Tags: c#, android-animation, maui, skiasharp, android-lottie

i'm kinda new into maui and this kind of animations. I've a custom filter control that checks if the entered data matches with something stored inside a dictionary. If something matches, the item source of the collection view is populated with these data (saved in an observable collection). If nothing matches, the collection view will be empty, so i've define the emptyview property of the collection view as such:

```
<CollectionView.EmptyView>
   <ContentView MinimumHeightRequest="485" IsVisible="{Binding IsEmpty}">
      <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                           Spacing="30"
                           Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
         <Grid HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
            <lottie:SKLottieView Source="earthanimation.json"
                                 RepeatCount="-1"
                                 HeightRequest="350"
                                 WidthRequest="350"
                                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Label Text="NOT FOUND" TextColor="LightBlue"
                   FontFamily="FAR" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
         </Grid>

         <Label Text="Location not found"
                FontSize="15" FontFamily="Conthrax"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
      </VerticalStackLayout>
   </ContentView>
</CollectionView.EmptyView>
```

Notice that i've binded the IsVisible property, this because when the filter entry was tapped, something triggered and the emptyview was showing, even though i didn't search for nothing. So i've made it visibile only when the actual search process returns 0 matches.
This just to clarify any doubts on that.

Everything is working fine, except for the lottie animation, it's not displaying what so ever, the only way to make it works, in debug, when the application is running, i've removed the lottie control, then once the UI refreshes, i've paste it back and it works....

I've no idea on how to resolve this.

I've tried to look up on the internet, but informations of this kind are really specific and really hard to find. So sadly i didn't find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried putting SKLottieView directly inside StackLayout instead of collectionview.empyview to see if the previous problem occurs?

Comment: Yes, if i place it outside the contentview.emptyview, and run the application, it works fine.  Looks like emptyview and this animation have some sort of incompatibility or so. I thought that i could user a generic container such as a grid, and display it when the the collection is empty, but i'd like to use the existing components/property for their purpose you know @JianweiSun-MSFT

Comment: So just don't use EmptyView and handle this yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can reproduce this issue. And I find a workaround, which is to remove Lottie first and add it again in code behind. Please consider the following code:

***For the xaml which consumes the lottie***.

**Please note that we should also add the lottie in the xaml**, otherwise it will not show.

```
<Button
   x:Name="CounterBtn"
   Text="Click me"
   SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
   Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}"
   HorizontalOptions="Center" />

....

<CollectionView.EmptyView>
   <ContentView MinimumHeightRequest="485" IsVisible="{Binding IsEmpty}">
      <VerticalStackLayout x:Name="mystack" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                           Spacing="30"
                           Margin="0, 0, 0, 0">
         <Grid x:Name="mygrid" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HeightRequest="350"
                                 WidthRequest="350">

           <skia:SKLottieView  x:Name="mylot" Source="dotnetbot.json"
                                   RepeatCount="-1"
                                   HeightRequest="350"
                                   WidthRequest="350"
                                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
           <Label Text="NOT FOUND" TextColor="Black"
               FontFamily="FAR" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>

         </Grid>

         <Label Text="{Binding MyText}"
                FontSize="15" FontFamily="Conthrax"
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
      </VerticalStackLayout>
   </ContentView>
```

***For ViewModel***, let's implement ClickedCommand. Please Note that I use [**MessagingCenter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter) here. Because when no item in collection we want to send a message to code behind to add the lottie again

```
    public Command ClickedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                ItemCollection.RemoveAt(0);
                if(ItemCollection.Count ==0)
                {
                    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPageViewModel>(this, "Hi");
                }

            });

        }
    }
```

In .NET 7, it is recommended to use [WeakReferenceMessenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger)  instead of MessagingCenter. The usages are similar.

***For code behind***, we just subscribe the message and we remove and add lottie again.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = viewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPageViewModel>(this, "Hi", (s) =>
    {
        mygrid.Clear();
        SKLottieView myanimatedview = new SKLottieView();
        var a = new SKFileLottieImageSource();
        a.File = "dotnetbot.json";
        myanimatedview.WidthRequest = 300;
        myanimatedview.HeightRequest = 300;
        myanimatedview.Source = a;
        myanimatedview.RepeatCount = -1;
        mygrid.Add(myanimatedview);
        Label label = new Label()
        {
            Text = "NOT FOUND",
            TextColor = Colors.LightBlue,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
        };
        mygrid.Add(label);
    });


}
```

For more info, you could refer to [SKLottieView](https://mono.github.io/SkiaSharp.Extended/api/ui-maui/sklottieview.html).You could also report an issue on Github:  [SKLottie Issues on Github](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended/issues)

Hope it helps!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ye, not really clean but it'll do the job for now, thank you very much. So it is a real bug/issue? Thought i was doing something wrong

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16584
link to the opened issue on github for everyone how might need it

Comment: I'm trying to use your code but im not fixing the issue. Where did you place this code? Inside an event or what?@LiqunShen-MSFT

Comment: Each time there is no item in the collection, you could then invoke these codes.

Comment: Ye i get it, but how? I went through the event list of the collection view but nothing looks like the right event to call... @Liqun

Comment: May I ask how do you change your observableCollection for itemSource in ViewModel?

Comment: `if (States.Count > 0) States.Clear();

try
{
IsExecuting = true;


if (potentialStates.Count > 0 && potentialStates.Count == potentialFlags.Count)
{
IsEmpty = false;
foreach (var potentialState in potentialStates)
{
 /*

States.Add(new State
{
Name = potentialState.Key,
ISO = potentialState.Value,
Sigle = sigle,
Flag = $"https://hatscripts.github.io/circle-flags/flags/{sigle.ToLower()}.svg",
CurrencySymbol = currencySymbol,
CurrencyName = currencyName
});
Progress += 0.6 / potentialStates.Count;
}
}
else IsEmpty = true;`

in the foreach loop States is list
@Liqun

Comment: Hello, I made a demo using a button to change the collection in viewModel. When the collection changes, I then send a message to code behind to add the lottie again. By the way, I have met a similar issue before:  [How to programatically start and stop lottie animations in .NET Maui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75170552/how-to-programatically-start-and-stop-lottie-animations-in-net-maui/75223956#75223956)

Comment: else
                {
                    IsEmpty = true;
                }

i would send the message to the code behind here, inside this else clause, but i don't know how @Liqun

Comment: in viewmodel ```else { IsEmpty = true;   MessagingCenter.Send<yourviewmodelname>(this, "Hi");}```
 and in code behind  ```public MainPage(){ MessagingCenter.Subscribe<yourviewmodelname>(this, "Hi", (s) =>
    {   add lottie again   }}```

Comment: Well, i was definetly not aware about this. I'll give it a try, thank you very much @Liqun

Comment: Don't worry. You could refer to [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter) and [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger). If you have any question, free to ask me.

Comment: im getting really annoyed... your code works, but there's somthing really weird going on. Basically the first time that the collection view is empty, the lottie does not display, but then yes... i think i'll make a pulic repo on github with this project so everybody can take a look at this. @Liqun

Comment: Nevermind  hero you go if you want to take a look [repo](https://github.com/AlbertoBvsso/CurrencyExchange). @Liqun

Comment: I made some changes in xaml. Please add the lottie in xaml. See my updates for xaml. I also add a gif to show the effect.

Comment: Just add the lottie  and label in xaml, then the first time also should work, just like my gif (it shows the first time).

Comment: ye, adding the lottie also in xaml, makes it display also the first time, well, hope this will get fixed someday, thank you very much for the help @Liqun

Comment: It's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

> if i place it outside the contentview.emptyview, and run the application, it works fine....

You can raise an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) for it (problem occurs when put SKLottieView into contentview.emptyview).

And if it's possible, don't use emptyview for now :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll open an issue on GitHub, but i think i'll follow the solution the has suggested the other guy, so hoping that the issue will be fix someday, i won't have to rewrite code.

Comment: I got it, and happy coding :)